# Using `tree`, how do I output files before subdirectories?

Tags: filesystems, ls, sort, tree

I tried to combine `--dirsfirst` and `-r`, but directories still show up on top, only in reverse alphabetical order. It seems like `-r` is applied first, which is also indicated by the man pages.

Any other ideas of how I would go about sorting the output of `tree` so that subdirectories are listed after the files?

Comment: try simple 'tree -r'

Comment: That will just reverse the alphabetical order.

Comment: nvm, I understood your question better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you came here looking for this answer (as I did), use:

```
tree --filesfirst
```

Option `--filesfirst` was added in [version 2.0.0](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/blob/master/CHANGES?ref_type=heads#L174) (12/21/2021)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `tree -r`, then reverse all lines, e.g., using `tac` and translate the box-characters it looks reasonable:

```
#!/bin/sh
tree --dirsfirst -r | tac | sed -e 's/\d226\d148\d148/\d226\d148\d140/'

# 0x2514 is lower-left-corner,
# 0x250c is upper-left-corner
# 0x2514: 9492 022424 0x2514 text "%\024" utf8 \342\224\224
# 0x250c: 9484 022414 0x250c text "%\014" utf8 \342\224\214
```

I got the Unicode value using the character-identifier in [vi-like-emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html), and the UTF-8 equivalent using my [`hex`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:hex) utility.

Here's the end of my `/etc` directory, to illustrate:

```
├── xdg
│   ┌── catalog
│   ├── catalog.old
│   ├── docbook-xml.xml
│   ├── docbook-xml.xml.old
│   ├── docbook-xsl.xml
│   ├── docbook-xsl.xml.old
│   ├── rarian-compat.xml
│   ├── sgml-data.xml
│   ├── sgml-data.xml.old
│   ├── xml-core.xml
│   ├── xml-core.xml.old
│   │   ┌── CatalogManager.properties
│   ├── resolver
├── xml
│   ┌── includes
│   ├── xpdfrc
├── xpdf
│   ┌── newuser.zshrc.recommended
│   ├── zlogin
│   ├── zlogout
│   ├── zprofile
│   ├── zshenv
│   ├── zshrc
├── zsh
.
```

For reference:

[UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters
page with code points U+2500 to U+25FF](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9472&unicodeinhtml=hex)

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy solution to make the output look the same as from tree? E.g. I would still like the files in subdirectories to be listed under the subdirectory rather than above it. So the small "tree-branches" would protrude downwards instead of upwards.

Comment: I don't think there is an *easy* solution (aside from modifying 'tree').